# JQuery datepicker to limit to first day of the current year and last day of the current year in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery-1.12.4 for my datepicker in Laravel-5.8

```
<input type="text" id="holiday_date" class="form-control" name="holiday_date" value="{{old('holiday_date')}}" >

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#holiday_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

    });
</script>
```

How to I limit the JQuery datepicker to :

1. first day of the current year
2. last day of the current year

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manipulate commencement date and resumption date using JQuery Date in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885289/how-to-manipulate-commencement-date-and-resumption-date-using-jquery-date-in-lar)

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called [yearRange](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) that will do this for a specific year, but if you want it to be dynamic, you can use [maxDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) and [minDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate).  Remember, the year starts at month 0 and ends at month 11:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#holiday_date').datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(year, 0, 1),
            maxDate: new Date(year, 11, 31)
       }
 }
```